# Boostrap Textarea allow select text

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, textarea

how can I allow the users to select text of a readonly bootstrap textarea.
Thats my current code:

```
   <div class="form-group">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" readonly style="height: 200px; max-width: 100%;"></textarea>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #888888;
}
```

Thank you
With best regards

Comment: What does "mark" mean?

Comment: sorry, i meant select

Comment: Ah, okay! Well then I'd recommend checking out this question, which may actual make yours a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript